# Getting values from a JSON that has separated string as keys

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a JSON that I would want to get the values from. However, the key values are typical key. They are not one worded.

```
[
    {
        "quality-of-service": "Good"
    },
    {
        "quality-of-staff": "Great"
    },
    {
        "quality-of-communication": "Excellent"
    },
    {
        "value-for-money": "Excellent"
    }
]
```

How do I get the values for the keys.

Comment: The same as any other array https://3v4l.org/2Tut8

Comment: @AbraCadaver so how do I get the value of the key `quality-of-staff` alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After decoding `$array = json_decode($json, true)`, the first value would be `$array[0]['quality-of-service']` which is not a good way to do it.  You could loop:

```
foreach($array as $values) {
    echo key($values) . " is " . current($values);
}
```

Or you can flatten the array:

```
$array = array_merge(...$array);
```

Then use `$array['quality-of-service']` or loop it:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key is $value";
}
```